# value.replace regex help needed with javascript function

Tags: javascript, regex

i am having a problem with some regex in a javascript function
My string looks like this...

> [Space]SomeString[Space][Tab]SomeString[Space][Tab][LineBreak]
>
> SomeString[LineBreak]
>
> [Space]SomeString[Space][Tab]SomeString[Space][Tab][LineBreak]
>
> SomeString[LineBreak]

I want to remove the [Tab][LineBreak] but keep the [LineBreak] so my output would be

> [Space]SomeString[Space][Tab]SomeString[Space]SomeString[LineBreak]
>
> [Space]SomeString[Space][Tab]SomeString[Space]SomeString[LineBreak]

I have tried:

```
value.replace(/\t\n/g, '');
```

but that didn't work i also tried:

```
value.replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

but that removed all the line breaks

Can anyone help please?
Thanks

Comment: I finally solved it thank goodness!!
You're not gonna believe this but the code was fine all along. I was echoing the script in php and it was converting the /t and /n into tabs and breaks in my source, so no wonder it didnt work. hahaha. Thanks for all the help tho guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick

```
str.replace(/\t(\r\n|\r|\n)/g,'');
```

Here is a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9fC4K/2/).

**Edit:**

```
str = str.replace(/^\s|\t([\r\n]+)|([\r\n]+)\t|\s$/g,'');
```

Here is the ["upgraded" example](http://jsfiddle.net/9fC4K/7/)

Comment: That will remove both the tab AND the line break.

Comment: That's right, tab+break is removed, but a break that is not preceded by tab will not.

Comment: i updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9fC4K/3/ with my exact string but used x's and o's. The fiddle works, but mine still doesnt?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9fC4K/6/ I used `str.replace(/^\s|\t([\r\n]+)|([\r\n]+)\t|\s$/g,'$2');`
So... `^\s` : the string begins with a whitespace; `\t([\r\n]+)` : the string contain a TAB followed by line break ; `([\r\n]+)((\t))` : the string contains a line break followed by a TAB ; `\s$` : the string ends with a whitespace. 
When any of these conditions matches then the matched content is removed.